# Javascript window.location.href.match not showing a code

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a javascript that will show some HTML code when the URL contains some word. I have the page where the URL is changing when you choose between input radio.

When the URL is https://example.com/tea-sticks/48-174-vanilla-arabica-sticks.html#/30-quantity-100/**42-acrylic-2** I need the JS to show some code. I have this but it's not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal} 
$(document).ready(function () {
if (window.location.href.match(/42-acrylic-2) {
<h1>TEST</h1> 
}
});
{/literal} 
</script>
```

Comment: What is `{literal}`?  Are there any errors in your browser's development console?  When you debug, what specifically happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("someId") > -1) {
       // handle
}
```

indexOf does exactly what it sounds it should - return index of your string. Youre not comparing to 0 to ensure you'll capture given string even if its 1st. Pls note that indexOf wont work on IE<8

Answer (score 0):

you can use includes instead of match

```js
if (window.location.href.includes('stack')) {
        alert('hi')
    }
```

Comment: In javascript, string does not have a built-in `contains()` method.

Comment: @PeterB sorry it is includes not contains, as contains comes after exmascript 6

Comment: The Chrome DevTools seem to run using the latest ECMAScript v6, which has `contains()`. In browser context however a lower language version is used, which does not have it. E.g. try the same in a Stack snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what to do with `{literal}` (?), but I assume this is what you want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.href.match('/42-acrylic-2')) {
    document.write('<h1>TEST</h1>')
  }
})
</script>
```

- You forgot your quotation marks in the match() function.
- You can not simply put HTML into JS, it won't know what to do with it. `document.write('HTML_CODE')` is one of the many ways js **can** insert HTML into the DOM.

Comment: Correct, although IMO `document.write(...);` is about the worst way to add something to a page + it should always be followed by `document.close();` so it renders correctly in all browsers. Also: `string.match()` doesn't return a bool, it returns an *array of matches*.

Comment: Absolutely true, but it is the simplest and most straightforward way to do it. I think when using jQuery a better way would be `append(...)`, but we don't know about the context. It seems like the purpose is to place some HTML into the DOM where the `<script>`-tag is located. It's not the most elegant way to do things, but I think it's as close to the question as possible.